Evaluating $\int\tan^{-1}(x^2+2)\,\mathrm dx$
I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$
\int\arctan\left(x^{2} + 2\right)\mathrm{d}x
$$
But I am not able to solve it in any way. Then I asked this question in $\tt WolframAlpha$, and it tells that
\begin{align}
\int\arctan\left(x^{2} + 2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
& =
x\arctan\left(x^{2} + 2\right)
\\ & \ -i\,\sqrt{2 - i}\,\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2 - i}}\right) \\ & \
+ i\,\sqrt{2 + i}\,\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2 + i}}\right) + \mbox{constant}
\end{align}
But I didn't understand how it answered the question.
I wanted to know the process but couldn't find it anywhere.
I hope someone can help me to solve this integral with the process included.

What have you tried? Also are you sure this was your original integral?

Please use MathJax - also, this form of the antiderivative suggests integration by parts.

Actually I don't know how to use MathJax. But the answer definitely involves complex terms which makes me feel that I can't solve it. But I wanted to know how it's done

WA integrates by parts, then insists on decomposing the subsequent integrand into partial fractions over $\Bbb C$

See here for MathJax use - it's very easy to pick up. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

The way I would solve this integral is by integration by parts:
$$\begin{align*}\int \tan^{-1}(x^2+2)dx &= x\tan^{-1}(x^2+2)-\int x\cdot \frac{2x}{(x^2+2)^2+1}dx. \end{align*}$$
Now notice that $$(x^2+2)^2 + 1 = x^4 + 4x^2 + 5 = (x^2+\sqrt 5)^2-(2\sqrt{5}-4)x^2 = (x^2+x\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}+\sqrt 5)(x^2-x\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}+\sqrt 5).$$
To simplify computations, I denote $\alpha := \sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}$. We proceed with fraction decomposition:
$$\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+2)^2+1} = \frac{Ax+B}{x^2+\alpha x + \sqrt 5} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2-\alpha x + \sqrt 5}.$$
After solving the system with unknowns $A,B,C,D\in \mathbb R$, we find that $C = - A = \frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $B=D=0$. Thus $$\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+2)^2+1} = \frac 1\alpha \left(\frac{x}{x^2-\alpha x + \sqrt 5} - \frac{x}{x^2+\alpha x + \sqrt 5}\right).$$
We now focus on $\displaystyle \int \frac{x}{x^2-\alpha x + \sqrt 5}dx$, as integrating the other term will be analogous. Let $u = x - \frac \alpha 2$, and now we are after $$\int \frac{u+\frac \alpha 2}{u^2 + \sqrt 5 - \frac{\alpha^2}{4}}du.$$
Notice that $\sqrt 5 - \frac{\alpha^2}{4} = 1+\frac{\sqrt 5}{2} = \frac 1 \alpha$ for later simplification.
Splitting the integral, we obtain:
$$\begin{align*}\int \frac{x}{x^2-\alpha x + \sqrt 5}dx &= \int \frac{u+\frac \alpha 2}{u^2 + 1+\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}}du \\ &= \frac 12\ln\left(u^2 + 1+\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}\right)+\frac \alpha 2\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}}}\right)+C\\&= \frac 12\ln\left(x^2 -\alpha x+\sqrt 5\right)+\frac{\alpha^{\frac 32}}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(x\sqrt \alpha -\frac{\alpha^{\frac 32}}{2}\right)+C.\end{align*}$$
Similarly (or by applying the variable change $t=-x$ to the previous integral), we obtain:
$$\begin{align*}\int \frac{x}{x^2+\alpha x + \sqrt 5}dx = \frac 12\ln\left(x^2 +\alpha x+\sqrt5\right)-\frac{\alpha^{\frac 32}}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(x\sqrt \alpha +\frac{\alpha^{\frac 32}}{2}\right)+C.\end{align*}$$
Finally, our original integral yields:
$$\int \tan^{-1}(x^2+2)dx = x\tan^{-1}(x^2+2)+\frac{1}{2\alpha}\ln\left(x^2 +\alpha x+\sqrt5\right)-\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(x\sqrt \alpha +\frac{\alpha^{\frac 32}}{2}\right)$$ $$-\frac{1}{2\alpha}\ln\left(x^2 -\alpha x+\sqrt5\right)-\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(x\sqrt \alpha -\frac{\alpha^{\frac 32}}{2}\right)+C.$$
